# why can does my code not find the element when it loops?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, pycharm

Everytime i run this bit of code it only manages to run once, once it goes to run the second time i get an error message saying that it cannot find the element from line 19. I've tried using the full xpath and the shorter xpath but nothing seems to work. can anyone help me? this is for a work project of mine. i've change the URL of the survey for privacy :)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


survey = webdriver.Chrome()


survey.get('https://www.surveygizmo.eu/s3/90221786/&sglocale=en')


feedback = open('/Users/xxxxxxxx/Desktop/ResponseVerbatim.txt', "r")


Response = feedback.readline()


while Response:
    # Enter the text into the survey form
    verbatim = survey.find_element("xpath", '/html/body/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/textarea')
    verbatim.send_keys(Response)

    # Click the "Next" button
    submit = survey.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="sg_NextButton"]')
    submit.click()

    # Wait for the next page to load
    time.sleep(5)

    # Select the satisfaction level
    satisfaction = survey.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="sgE-90221786-35-77-10397-handle"]')
    satisfaction.click()

    # Click the "Next" button
    submit3 = survey.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="sg_NextButton"]')
    submit3.click()

    # Read the next line of text from the file
    Response = feedback.readline()

feedback.close()
```

I've made a similar programme before and it had no issue. The programme is meant to open and read the text file and submit the responses from the text file, line by line, until all the lines have been submitted. The issue I'm having is after the first response has been submitted, i get an error message saying "no such element unable to locate element" for line 19.

Ive tried using the long xpath and the short xpath to see if that makes a difference but it doesn't seem to.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxxxxxxx/PycharmProjects/seleniumpython/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    verbatim = survey.find_element("xpath", '/html/body/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/textarea')
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxxxxxx/PycharmProjects/seleniumpython/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 861, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxxxxxx/PycharmProjects/seleniumpython/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 444, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/xxxxxxx/PycharmProjects/seleniumpython/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 249, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/textarea"}
  (Session info: chrome=108.0.5359.124)
```

Comment: we don't have HTML or url(privacy) , so it's hard to tell why it's unable to locate the element. You could try waits, [source](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: The element wasn't on the page, simple as that.  To help yourself figure out _why_ this happens, save the page source to a file when this error happens and then look at it.  Hopefully the page will have some clue as to why the element was missing.

Comment: NoSuchElementException is because of invalid locator, check your locator.  Without the correct URL, we can't suggest any solution.

Comment: _Everytime i run this bit of code it only manages to run once, once it goes to run the second time i get an error message saying that it cannot find the element from line 19_ If this is so, then you have an obvious way to debug the problem.  Open the url in a regular browser session and perform the code steps by hand (fill out the form, click submit, etc.) The problem should then become apparent.